# How can a materialized view be created when exporting a collection from Firestore to BigQuery using "Stream Firestore to BigQuery"?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I'm utilizing the **Stream Firestore to BigQuery** extension to transfer and synchronize records from Firestore to BigQuery. Presently, the extension only generates standard views for the designated change log table. I'm interested in creating a materialized view with this extension. Is it feasible, and if so, how can it be achieved?

I've attempted the instructions provided in the document you mentioned, but it seems to only generate standard views and not materialized views.
documents links are [here](https://extensions.dev/blogs/stream-firestore-to-bigquery) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/next/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/GENERATE_SCHEMA_VIEWS.md)

Comment: Hi @Ahmad, you can create the materialized view in the BigQuery console using the [queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#create). Let me know if this is helpful or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and accurate response! @DhirajSingh Your solution worked perfectly for me, and I truly appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me out.

Comment: @DhirajSingh How can I map the Firestore fields to the bigQuery table using Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension? Right now it stores the complete document in the data column and it's also in JSON string. I can create the view but I want to add all Firestore fields to the bigQuery column.

Comment: As far as I know, using the `stream Firestore to BigQuery` extension, it's not possible, but a workaround is you can try to upload the json file to GCP cloud storage and [create an external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#create-external-table) in BigQuery from the cloud storage. That might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirements, you can create the materialized views in the BigQuery console using queries mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#create).